# I can't connect my washing machine properly. Please help

Tags: washing-machine, hose, fitting, tap

I got an old washing machine From my grandparents but I can't seem to fit the hose into the tap. There are in my opinion 2 problems, there are 2 male connections instead of a female and a male and I think the size is not right. Thanks so much for your help!

The hose to the washing machine:
[image]

[image: the input washing machine]

The faucet:
[image]

Comment: a side view of the tap, and what the washing machine model is (to double check the manual) might be helpful. There's *generally* adaptors - and also, you have two female connectors. On our tap, there was a screw in bit that converted to something the washing machine could fit into. Is the washing machine end threaded, or something that looks like a push connector?

Answer (score 3):

A female connection on the outlet side of a tap is unusual.  As Journeyman Geek said, a side view of the tap could possibly show that your solution is as simple as removing a female-female fitting to expose a male thread that your washer will connect to.

If it is indeed a female outlet on the tap, make sure there is a gasket in it before you connect a male-male fitting that your washer will connect to.